# PCC100 Harvest Design

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, energy-harvesting

I want to do harvest design with [PCC100 IC](https://powercastco.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/PCC110-PCC210-Overview-V1.6-ONE-PAGE-1.pdf) but I couldn't find much documentation so I wonder that what is the RF input voltage relation and IC output voltage between. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [their website](https://www.powercastco.com/receivers/) they're stating: **full PCC110 datasheet and reference designs available under NDA**.

So even if somebody here *could* theoretically help you, it wouldn't be permitted by the NDA.

Your only option is to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will contact the manufacturer.